# How to make a device securely communicate with a remote Database?

Tags: python, mysql

I created my first micro controller device and I want it to push data to a website. Basically it collects data and I want to store that in a database. But there are multiple devices and I don't want the devices to be able to read the data other devices uploaded. Now I wonder what the safest method would be?

The server runs Debian and I have full access. The device runs Debian as well and I'm coding in python.

Those are the ideas I came up with:

- make the device fill out forms on a website
- make the device connect to MYSQL directly

So what is the easiest way to make this right? Filling out forms seems the easiest to me, but is it really a good practice to just send POST data? How can I deal with authentication?

Conneting to the Mysql seems bad, because I don't really want to grant access to the whole table. But maybe a "add only - no read" restriction could work.

Comment: You already have a website? If you do, what technologies does it use?

Comment: I'd recommend a web service for the updates. There are a lot of security schemes you can implement. The first that comes to mind is to have the device provide credentials when calling the web service - either pass username/password each time, or log in with username/password and get a token to use on subsequent calls (and expire the token every few minutes). Same thing if the device has to read: it provides the credentials, which indicate which data it can see. If you're new to this, try getting the read and write stuff done first, then add the security later.

Comment: I guess restricting the permissions is a neat KISS way to do it. If you manage to restrict the device's permissions to just a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query, that might do.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you use some web framework

1. Use REST api to your web site. Most web framework has REST api extension.
2. only permit PUT, POST permission, not GET

For example, I am using django + tastypie. tastypie provide rest api for accessing django models and also provide authentication and authorization. [Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) is another good choice